# git commit --amend - commit hash is changed when no changes are made

Tags: git, hash, commit, git-amend

I open for some correction of my understanding of this, but I am not sure why this happens.

When using git, I understand that if I make a change to a file and then commit it I get a new hash because the file has changed.

My understanding of `git commit --amend` is that I can make changes to the last commit.

Now I can understand that if I change the commit message, the hash will change.

But when I do not make any changes and just save and exit out of the editor (I may have changed my mind on needing a change) why does the hash change? 
All my files and everything is the same, but I have saved it. When I of a `git log` the time of the commit hasn't changed, it just appears twice in the log with the same time, the same message, same files except a different commit hash.

Why does it change if no alterations have been done??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git hashes are calculated using a number of items, including the author name/date, commit name/date commit message, tree, and parent SHA, among others. When you amend a commit, the *commit* name and date are updated. (You generally don't see the commit name and date unless you pass additional formatting options to `git log`.) Because that has been updated, the commit hash will change when a commit is amended.

Comment: mipadi is totally right. You just created a new commit itself and added the previous commit's changes to it, supplanting the previous commit.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you for the update. So just to clarify is there anyway that no changes are made and the hash isn't altered??

Comment: @JeffKranenburg: There is, in fact. If you keep the committer author and date the same when you amend a commit, and make no other relevant changes, the hash will stay the same. You can override the committer author and date using the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variables.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg: However, if you simply want to abort a `git commit --amend`, it's probably easier to just delete the entire commit message when Git prompts you to edit it. Git won't accept an empty message and will abort the commit instead.

Comment: Awesome I will have a play around with that.

Comment: Just did some more playing around and if I do not make any changes to anything at all, including the date and author, but safe the file the commit hash changes. I am not sure why, but that is how it is on my system.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg: Hm, I don't know. I tested it and it worked. Here's a rough log of what I did: https://gist.github.com/mdippery/2d9b4245c12fa615e935